# How do I programatically get a large iPad window on startup with MonoTouch?

Tags: cocoa-touch, ipad, mono, xamarin.ios

I have the latest Ipad compatible Monotouch library. I have upgraded my projects to use 3.2 SDK and MonoTouch 1.9 Alpha.

The docs say you need to change the Window in your XIB for the large iPad Window. I don't use XIB. I build my interface from code by constructing the object programatically. What should I be doing to get the large iPad style Window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After further investigation, I found that I needed to add an entry into the info.plist file like so:

```
Information Property List
     UIDeviceFamily
          item 0            2
```

Once this is present the dynamic Window class that I create is the full iPad screen size.

I think it is basically telling the system that my app supports that device. Will have to find our more in the docs.

Comment: Actually you can find such an entry in the Project/Target info (Cmd+I).

Comment: my project was originally just iPhone. So I had to add it.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing (I assume).

`[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds` (and its equivalent on MonoTouch) will be 768x1024 in iPad mode and 320x480 in iPhone mode. If your windows and views do not have any hard-coded values they should adopt to the new size naturally.

Comment: or not until you tell the app to run as an iPad app.